# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: crypto.subtle.digest is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jestjs

I am getting "crypto.subtle.digest is not a function" while running unit tests with Jest for a function which uses crypto.subtle.digest() for hashing. I am using JSDOM and I have tried these two options with no luck:

```
 1. `[How to use Jest to test functions using crypto or window.msCrypto][1]`

    Object.defineProperty(global.self, 'crypto', {
              value: {
                subtle: crypto.subtle,
              }
            });
```

2. `global.crypto.subtle = {};`

Comment: @Hardik Modha  any clue?

Answer (score 0):

```js
import { webcrypto } from 'crypto';
import { TextEncoder } from 'util';

import { digest } from './digest';

describe('digest', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    Object.defineProperties(global, {
      crypto: { value: webcrypto, writable: true },
      TextEncoder: { value: TextEncoder, writable: true },
    });
  });

  it('creates a SHA256 digest', async () => {
    expect(await digest('test')).toEqual(
      '9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08'
    );
  });
});
```

digest.js:

```js
async function digest(message, algo = 'SHA-256') {
  return Array.from(
    new Uint8Array(
      await crypto.subtle.digest(algo, new TextEncoder().encode(message))
    ),
    (byte) => byte.toString(16).padStart(2, '0')
  ).join('');
}
```